# Concurrent-safe queue in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to create thread safe queue with unique elements. I see no vulnerabilities but not sure still is this realisation thread safe or not? get(), add(), toArray() methods do everything under lock, toString() and equals() use toArray() in order to get main array copy and work independently with copy without locks.

```
public class SafeQueue<T> {
        private final Object[] queue;
        private final HashSet<T> content;
        private final Lock lock;
        private int size;
        
        public SafeQueue() {
            queue = new Object[100];
            content = new HashSet<>(100);
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
        }

        public boolean add(T el) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(el);
            final Lock lock = this.lock;
            lock.lock();
            try {
               //some logic
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public T get() {
            final Lock lock = this.lock;
            lock.lock();
            try {
                T el = (T) queue[0];
                if (el != null) {
                    //some shift logic
                    content.remove(el);
                }
                return el;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public Object[] toArray() {
            final Lock lock = this.lock;
            lock.lock();
            try {
                return Arrays.copyOf(this.queue, size);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Object[] eqQueue = ((SafeQueue<?>) o).toArray();
            Object[] curQueue = toArray();

            //some comparison logic with eqQueue and curQueue
            return equal;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            Object[] curQueue = toArray();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append('[');
            //some logic with curQueue
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the `final Lock lock = this.lock;` lines?

Comment: IMO, your `equals(...)` method would be more efficient if it simply locked the lock and compared the original two arrays. In your version, it locks and unlocks twice, it creates and destroys two new arrays, it copies two arrays, and it still hast to compare two arrays.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I was thinking about it and my thoughts were like instead of holding a lock for the entire duration of equals() I hold the lock only during the call to toArray() and it's less disruptive for other threads accessing the queue. But I have two calls toArray() method so maybe yes it's less efficient

Comment: See my late answer, below, that talks about whether or not your equals method really is as thread-safe as you might suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to ask, what does it mean for the `equals` method to be thread safe? Consider this:

```java
SafeQueue<T> qa = ...;
SafeQueue<T> qb = ...;
...
if (qa.equals(qb)) {
    handleEqualsCase();
}
```

If you had any reason to worry about the thread-safety of the `equals()` method, that could only be because other threads potentially could modify either queue when `equals()` is called.

But, by the time `handleEqualsCase()` is called, those other threads still could be running, and now, neither `qa` nor `qb` is locked. There is no guarantee that the two queues *still* will be equal when `handleEqualsCase()` is called. But, if they're not equal, that must be a Bad Thing, right? Otherwise, why would you have bothered to test for equality in the first place?

Here's one way around that problem. Instead of writing a traditional `equals()` method, write something like this instead:

```java
private static
boolean unsynchronizedEqualityTest(SafeQueue<T> qa, SafeQueue<T> qb) {
    ...
}

public static
void doIfEqual(SafeQueue<T> qa, SafeQueue<T> qb, Runnable handler) {
    qa.lock.lock();
    qb.lock.lock();
    try {
        if (unsynchronizedEqualityTest(qa, qb)) {
            handler.run();
        }
    } finally {
        qb.lock.unlock();
        qa.lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Now, when the client-supplied `handler` is invoked, it's guaranteed that the two queues still will be equal because they're both still locked.

---

But BEWARE! There's potential for a deadlock if one thread calls `doIfEqual(qa,qb,...)` and another thread calls `doIfEqual(qb,qa,...)`. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to prevent that deadlock from happening.

Comment: Yes, this equals() method is one of my doubts. Thanks for advice, I'll take a look at this more closely in this way

Comment: And also one point - actually if my queue is thread-safe I have to guarantee that it will be safe to use queue.equals() - but I can't guarantee what will happen later after check

Comment: @dallin_sh, The `equals()` method that you wrote is "thread-safe" in the sense that it won't crash your program, and it won't hurt the queue if one thread calls it while other threads are concurrently using the queues; but just because all of the objects in some program are thread-safe, that does not automatically make the whole program thread-safe. The API of your `equals()` method makes it impossible for the _client code that calls it_ to be thread-safe. The API of my `doIfEqual(...)` on the other hand, _can_ be used in a thread-safe way.

Comment: Yes, i see it..and i noticed even ConcurrentHashMap from java.util package has such annotation to its equals() method - 'Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is a map with the same mappings as this map. This operation may return misleading results if either map is concurrently modified during execution of this method.'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your implementation is thread safe.